# Solving recurrences using generating functions

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I have the following solution for solving a recurrence using a generating function and I have a question on why it is multiplied by (1-z) and why this causes the second summand to disappear. [image]

Comment: $z$ seems to be back in the line after the next line. So, just a typo I guess.

Comment: The limit on the sum changed, as did the the exponent on the z inside. Note that the exponent on the 2 has been mistakenly written as a subscript instead of a superscript.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. What is happening in the next line after the next line, why is A(z) multiplied by (1-z) and why does that cause the second summand to disappear?

Answer (score 2):

After correcting the typos, we have

$$\begin{align*}
A(z)&=2+z\sum_{n\ge 1}a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+z\sum_{n\ge 1}2^{n-1}z^{n-1}\\
&=2+z\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nz^n+z\sum_{n\ge 0}2^nz^n\\
&=2+zA(z)+z\sum_{n\ge 0}2^nz^n\;,
\end{align*}$$

since $A(z)=\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nz^n$. Now just subtract $zA(z)$ from both sides to get

$$(1-z)A(z)=A(z)-zA(z)=2+z\sum_{n\ge 0}2^nz^n\;.$$

Comment: In the next line, the sum is replaced by 1/(1-2z). Why is that?

Comment: @user2057890: Sum of a geometric series with first term $1$ and ratio $2z$: $2^nz^n=(2z)^n$.